# Comments not displaying after changing theme

Tags: themes, comments

The 'Leave a Reply' section at the end of my posts are not displaying after changing to the 'The Morning After' theme. Comments and reply sections are displaying when I revert to the Twenty Eleven theme. I have tried re-installing the theme but it is still not working. Example post at: http://richashworth.com/testing/

Comment: 1: is that a post or a page? 2: can you post the code for the relevant template? 3: Are you sure the theme actually implements comments? A lot of themes don't have comment forms or comments on their pages 4: what does your error log say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the kerfuffle of logging in and acquiring the theme, I got to the code:

```
$comm = get_option( 'woo_comments' );
if ( 'open' == $post->comment_status && ($comm == 'post' || $comm == 'both' ) ) {
    comments_template( '', true );
}
```

Your comments are not showing because in the woothemes settings, they have not been set to show for posts.

In future I recommend you look through all options and configuration panels, a quick skim read should resolve these issues